# How to create product bundle or similar to that?

Tags: commerce

I have a plan to create a e-commerece website for Computer Assembling. 
I have exp in Prestatshop and few other CMS (e-commerce) framework.
In that i found Drupal 7 is having the best one like durpalecommerece. So I selected Drupal 7 as CMS framework.
I download few modules ubercart and tried e-commerce module also.

But its not meeting my requirements. My requirement is

1. Homepage - User can see All default PC set (Monitor, CPU, Keyboard and Mouse) with price.
2. Select PC, Next page description will display.
3. Defualt Product piece is 1, but the user can increase more.
4. Based on the increase Rate will be changed.

Above steps are working fine. Below steps are not working.

1. Homepage - If user doesn't happy with default PC set, User can build there own PC
2. Select "Build own PC".
3. List of Monitor companies and inches will display.
4. User selects one monitor and click,
5. It will redirect to CPU Parts.
6. User will select Mother board, ram, hardisk ... one by one
7. On click "NEXT" redirect to shopping cart....

How to achive Product bundle here to get calculate amount in cart

Comment: Hello and welcome. Have you tried to make some research on your own? We can't build functionality for scratch for you here.

Answer (score 1):

For building a e-commerce website you should try the [drupal commerce](https://drupal.org/project/commerce) module or [commerce_kickstart](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) (If you are novice with drupal then commerce_kickstart is the option).
**Drupal Commerce**

> Core Features
>
> Create product types with custom attributes
>   Dynamic product displays
>   Order management, line item
>   Payment method API, allowing many different payment gateways 
>   Tax calculation / VAT support 
>   Discount pricing rules 
>   Deep integration with systems like D7's Fields, Views,Rules and Entity API.

**Commerce Kickstart**

> Commerce Kickstart is the quickest way to get up and running with
>   Drupal Commerce. It includes the latest versions of Drupal core,
>   Drupal Commerce, and the other modules it depends on. It also gives
>   you a set of options to create a fully-featured demo store out of the
>   box complete with an attractive theme, catalog and search
>   configuration, and a custom back office interface.
>   Who should use Commerce Kickstart? Anyone who wants to skip weeks of
>   configuration to build a commerce site on the Drupal Commerce
>   framework.

Comment: I only want to say that I would advise using Commerce over Ubercart (the other big Drupal eCommerce module).  Ubercart is old, messy, and the documentation is becoming dated.